# Averaging over a table based on criteria not being met

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that can't have headers (or I think I could use dsum for this, I have included headers in the example table for ease of explanation), I want to work out the average "price per" when bought or sold, but only if the row doesn't match a list of names.

So if I wanted to do this for all entries (rows) where items were Bought, but not if Origin was "SWAP" or "G COMM", I would look at the first row, see A it doesn't match "SWAP" or "G COMM", add C to a COUNT variable, and add B*C to a TOTAL variable. I would do this for all rows and at the end do TOTAL/COUNT to get the average "Price Per" based on how many were bought not matching my criterium.

So for that example, row 1 & 3 are bought rows with matching Origin criteria, ((18*5)+(17*3))/(5+3) = Average Price Per of 17.625

| (A) Origin | (B) Price Per | (C) Bought | (D) Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CITIZEN | 18 | 5 |  |
| " | 20 |  | 14 |
| " | 17 | 3 |  |
| " | 20 |  | 3 |
| COMM | 24 |  | 5 |
| CITIZEN | 19 |  | 2 |
| SWAP | 14 | 16 |  |
| G COMM | 0 |  | 4 |

Comment: Would you please edit your answer to include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: `I want to work out the average price paid when bought or sold` I'm sorry but I don't understand this. The "bought** average is the value in Column C; OTOH the "sold" average requires a **cumulative weighted average** of purchases and sales. Also, the data requires an opening stock qty and value; "Citizen" has 115 units in stock (at some unknown average price) prior to the initial purchase - doesn't this transaction need to be included in order to accurately calculate the average.

Comment: imho, [AVERAGEIFS](https://exceljet.net/functions/averageifs-function) is what u r 
looking for.. set a criteria with "<>" should do.. right?

Comment: Hopefully this edit makes it clearer what I'm trying to do. A cumulative weighted average is outside of the scope of detail needed for this sheet.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/docs) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `FILTER` the data as needed
- get both the filtered columns using `INDEX` and calculate as needed

```
=LET(data,
  FILTER(B1:D8,
    A1:A8<>"SWAP",
    A1:A8<>"G COMM", 
    C1:C8<>""),
  priceper,INDEX(data,0,1), 
  qty,INDEX(data,0,2), 
  SUMPRODUCT(priceper*qty)/SUM(qty)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to mostly work, the only issue with it is it will error if all the rows are filtered out. How would it be possible to return 0 if there are no unfiltered rows?

Comment: @solexious Tried `IFNA`?

Comment: ah thanks, I didn't know if there was something to add into the let rather than wrapping it in an IFNA. Thanks very much